# C++ Circular Link List - remove all nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to remove all the nodes in singly circular linked list. But I got following Error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1005068f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Following is the function:

```
void StudentLinkList::removeAll() {
    StudentData *traversePointer = this->head;

    while (this->head != nullptr) {
        this->head = this->head->getNext();
        delete traversePointer;
        traversePointer = nullptr;
        traversePointer = this->head;
        this->size--;
    }
}
```

I get error on this line:

```
delete traversePointer;
```

My question is that why traversePointer not allocated in while loop as shown in the error?

Comment: you probably want to fix the error, but what is your question?

Comment: In a circular linked list, what makes you think `this->head = this->head->getNext();` will work when you get back to the start? Use a debugger ....

Comment: The error is quite frankly very descriptive... You should be really glad about that... I wish I received these kind of errors...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Because I am deleting all the previous nodes in while loop. And this->head will become null eventually.

Comment: Instead of custom logic, have `removeAll` call `remove` on the first node until the list is empty.

Comment: @IdreesAshraf I bet you $10 it wont. Use a debugger and find out.

Comment: @user4581301 Your logic works perfect. But I am interested to know why I am facing error on my own logic. seems like compiler not deleting the nodes on time in loop.

Comment: @IdreesAshraf you never set `this->head` to `nullptr`, with `traversePointer = nullptr;` you set that `traversePointer` points to `nullptr` and then immediately in the next line pointing to `this->head`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while should be:

```
    while(this->size){
```

When the loop completes, then set this->head = nullptr. There's no need to set traversePoitner = nullptr in the loop.

Alternative version (I haven't confirmed this yet), that doesn't rely on this->size being correct, only that the list is circular:

```
void StudentLinkList::removeAll() {
    if(this->head == nullptr)
        return;
    StudentData *traversePointer = this->head;
    StudentData *deletePointer;
    do{
        deletePointer = traversePointer;
        traversePointer = traversePointer->getNext();
        delete deletePointer;
    }while(traversePointer != this->head);
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why I need to set this->head = nullptr when I am already deleting and setting traversePoitner to null? At the end traverse pointer will be same as head. So setting traverse pointer to null will set the head pointer to null automatically.

Comment: @IdreesAshraf - this->head is a pointer to node. traversePointer is a separate pointer to node and a copy of this->head, not a reference to this->head. Also when the loop completes, this->head will be back to it's original value because it's a circular list.

Comment: I got it. Just a little confusion, traversePoiner and head pointer are pointing to same object. So if I delete traversePointer will not it delete the same object that both pointers are pointing to?

Comment: `traversePointer` is a copy of `head`. It is not `head`. Changing the copy does absolutely nothing to the source. But think of what would happen is you set `head` to `nullptr` along with `traversePointer`: `traversePointer = this->head;` would set `traversePointer` to `nullptr`.

Comment: @IdreesAshraf - it will delete the object, but it won't globally change all pointers to that object to nullptr.

Comment: So if object is get deleted then it will be still in memory? will not compiler set it to null right after deleting it?

Comment: @IdreesAshraf - deleting the object will not set all pointers to that object to nullptr.

Comment: The object is deleted. it MAY still be in memory until another allocation needs that space, but assume it is no longer usable and don't use it. There could be billions of pointers to one object. The compiler or the runtime has no hope of tracking them all down to NULL them without some seriously groovy and very expensive extra work and book-keeping, so they don't even try.